# usar useRef y no querySelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, hook

Estoy haciendo aprendiendo react y quiero entender el hook useRef() pero hay algo que no me queda claro y donde si se puede utilizar y donde no ya que el tener este codigo en react y yo quiero acceder solamente al segundo elemento span:

```
import './presentation.css'

export function Presentation () {
  const secText = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const textSecond = secText.current
    console.log(textSecond.current)
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={secText} className='conteiner-presentation'>
        <span className='text first-text'>Yo soy </span>
        <span className='text sec-text'> Facundo Romo</span>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

lo cual funciona pero en la consola me lanza el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero no lo termino de entender y buscando en internet no encontre algo que me pueda explicar una forma de acceder a ese elemento span unicamente

Comment: asegurate de importar useRef, el ref={secText} debe ir en el segundo span no en el contenedor si queres referirte al segundo span, quita el undefined de la definicion del useRef

Answer (score 0):

Te falta importar las funciones `useEffect` y `useRef` de react.
También, la referencia se la debes asignar al segundo `span` que es al que quieres acceder.
Una vez asignado `textSecond`, ese ya no tiene `current`, ese ya es el elemento como tal.

```js
const {useEffect,useRef} = React

function App(props) {
  const secText = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const textSecond = secText.current;
    console.log(textSecond.textContent); //" Facundo Romo"
  }, []);


  return (
      <div className='conteiner-presentation'>
        <span className='text first-text'>Yo soy </span>
        <span ref={secText} className='text sec-text'> Facundo Romo</span>
      </div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( <App/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```